# use dynamic component loader in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-loading

I have created following application using dynamicComponentloader of angular2 using typeScript.
But my child component is not getting rendered.
[image: Snapshot of my app]

my component:

```
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer,DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {DynamicBody1Component} from './ICICI-DYNAMIC-BODY-1.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[x-large]'
})
export class XLarge {
  constructor(element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    // we must interact with the dom through Renderer for webworker/server to see the changes
    renderer.setElementStyle(element.nativeElement, 'fontSize', 'x-large');
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [
    ...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    XLarge
  ],
  styles: [`
    .router-link-active {
      background-color: lightgray;
     }`
    ],
  template: `
    <div>    
        <div>
            <span x-large>Hello, {{ name }}!</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div #container></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `
 })
export class App {
  name: string = 'Angular 2';
  public dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader;  
  constructor(dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader, private     elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(DynamicBody1Component, this.elementRef, 'container');

  }
}
```

is anything wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an up-to-date example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

**original**

You can't use `dynamicComponentLoader` in `constructor()` anymore. Move it to `ngOnInit()`

```
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer,DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {DynamicBody1Component} from './DYNAMIC-BODY-1.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[x-large]'
  host: {
    '[style.fontSize]': 'x-large',
  }
})
export class XLarge {
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [
    ...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    XLarge
  ],
  styles: [`
    .router-link-active {
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
  `],
  template: `
  <div>    
    <div>
      <span x-large>Hello, {{ name }}!</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div #container></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  name: string = 'Angular 2';
  constructor(private dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(DynamicBody1Component, this.elementRef, 'container');

  }
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution,now i am getting this error;`EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadIntoLocation' of undefined in [null]
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadIntoLocation' of undefined`...see the updated code in question

Comment: Sorry, forgot to delete a line in `App` before the constructor.

Comment: @gunter.its still not working.for details plz refer the snapshot. I am using universal-starter for serverside rendering. no error is displayed.but my component is also not getting loaded in browser.

Comment: But you don't get an error? I also changed `XLarge`. You don't need `ElementRef` for this. This won't fix the problem though.

Comment: @guner if you can refer the snapshot , you can see that no error is given in console,but component is not getting loaded.

Comment: its working for normal angular2 app.but i am using this in universal-starter.thus I am facing the problem.

Comment: I don't know about Universal, but I guess it's pretty much the same when run on the client.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, Can you please provide link for loading dynamic template in stable version of Angular2. thnx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 It's about dynamic component loading not dynamic template loading.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thnx for response, I have requirement like I have multiple html templates and based on condition(if condition), I like to load different- different template, can you please suggest me how to do?

Comment: Why do you need to load the dynamically instead of adding it statically? If you really need to load them dynamically you have to create components dynamically at runtime. There are answers to this topic already. I don't know details about it myself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Hi I searched for dynamic component but I found all example which is deprecated in stable version. Can you please provide me link for that on stable version.

Comment: Searching for `compile` or `compiler` might help. I just remember that there were questions about this topic with answers, but this use case isn't interesting to me and ignored this topic.